# Accessing Json with square brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, json

In Rails, how do I access the individual elements of this json? I parsed it using ruby's .to_json method.`json = CSV.parse(csv).to_json`.
Here's what is returned:

```
[
[
    "id", 
    "subject"
], 
[
    "1", 
    "Economics"
], 
[
    "2", 
    "General Paper"
], 
[
    "3", 
    "History"
], 
[
    "4", 
    "Geography"
], 
[
    "5", 
    "Mathematics"
], 
[
    "6", 
    "Chemistry"
], 
[
    "7", 
    "Biology"
], 
[
    "8", 
    "Physics"
]
```

]

Trying to access `json[0][1]` or `json[0]` returns `"["`

I have a feeling it has to do with the square brackets but I'm sure there's a way to access it (It looks like arrays in an array to me and that means of access should work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert the data to JSON it becomes a JSON string. If you access it as an array you'll just get the character item referenced.

If you just want access to the data drop the to_json bit. The CSV parse should give you back the array of arrays and you can access it how you want.